# How to indent with the tab character with a visual length of 4 spaces in spacemacs?

Tags: spacemacs, indentation

I have used Vim for years now, Emacs for a couple of weeks and recently switched to Spacemacs. How do I set indentation settings either globally or the C/C++ mode? (A solution for either one is fine.) I've put the following in my `dotspacemacs/user-config ()` function in my `.spacemacs` file.

```
  (setq-default indent-tabs-mode t)
  (setq-default tab-width 4)                ; tabs four spaces wide
  (defvaralias 'c-basic-offset 'tab-width)  ; Set the C/C++/Java.. mode to use this tab width
```

But neither is it using tabs (it's using spaces) nor is the tab-width 4 (it's 2). Is this supposed to work? If not, what's the way to set tab indentation and tab-width for either a specific mode or globally in Spacemacs? (The settings above worked for me in the init.el for vanilla Emacs.)

Comment: Don't use tabs.  It makes your code display differently across different editors and operating systems.

Comment: Well.. that's kind of the point. I want readers of my code to be able to adjust it to their preferences. However, I do want to _align_ code (with respect to the line above) with spaces after the indentation level. I just want the indentation level to be attained with tabs. Eg., some people find 8-length indentation easier to read. I want 4-length indentation. But I'll think about it - perhaps using spaces will make my life easier.

Comment: It's a good idea, but for instance your configuration will not display code that assumes a tab width of 8 correctly.  Just try viewing some of the Emacs source code and you will see what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Emacs doesn't blindly add shifts when pressing TAB. Instead, it uses "indentation style" to deduce indentation intelligently from the surrounding mode.

For example with the default indentation style, `gnu`, Emacs uses 2 spaces.

To change the indentation mode type `C-c .` when editing the file, and choose preferred mode (use `TAB` for completion). For example I mostly use `stroustrup`, which uses 4 spaces.

To make it permanent, set the `c-default-style` variable in your init file:

```
(setq c-default-style "stroustrup")
```

More about C indentation: [EmacsWiki - Indenting C](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IndentingC)

Comment: Oh I didn't know about styles. Thanks. However, even with the Stroustrup style, it still uses spaces. I added `(setq-default indent-tabs-mode t) (setq-default tab-width 4)` back, and I think it's good now.

Comment: But those options did simply work in Emacs and I could combine them with smart-tabs-mode. Spacemacs seems more picky.